# Visual Studio 2013 not displaying C# compile errors - only displays "unable to copy dll from /obj/ to /bin/ folder"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

there are two developers that I work with who are experiencing a very strange issue with their Visual Studio 2013 IDE. The problem started for one developer a few weeks ago... and then it began with another developer on a different project just today.

When building C# code which contains any compile errors the IDE does not display the list of compile errors... the build process continues on and attempts to copy the compiled DLL from the /obj/ folder into the /bin/ folder as though the build had succeeded. An error is then thrown and displayed on the error list "unable to copy /obj/Debug/xxx.dll to /bin/Debug. Unable to access /obj/xxx.dll" ... this is because the /obj/xxx.dll never got created since the source code doesn't compile. **NOTE: This is not an issue where another process has a .dll file locked**

If we take the exact same source code and open it up on another machine running VS2013 and run the build you will see the compile errors. You can even go back and fix these compile errors on the affected machines and build successfully.

Is there a setting somewhere in Visual Studio to "ignore compilation errors and continue with build process as though the build had succeeded" - I'm pretty familiar with MSBuild and I know of no such setting. So this is a bit baffling to me - it almost seems like some sort of VS2013 bug.

---

EDIT - here are the diagnostic build log differences between a machine with the issue and one without the issue. You can see the output which gets sent to the console when csc.exe is executed on the machine where everything works... but you don't see any output from csc.exe on the machine with the issue. Yet... no errors present themselves until the Copy task attempts to copy the .dll from /obj/ to /bin/ ...

**Machine with issue**

```
1>Using "Csc" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "Csc" (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:DebugType=full (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:DefineConstants=DEBUG;TRACE (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:DisabledWarnings=;1701;1702;2008 (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:EmitDebugInformation=True (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:ErrorEndLocation=True (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:ErrorReport=prompt (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:FileAlignment=512 (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:HighEntropyVA=True (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:NoConfig=True (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:NoStandardLib=True (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:Optimize=False (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:OutputAssembly=obj\Debug\CRDReportingClasses.dll (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:Prefer32Bit=False (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:PreferredUILang=en-US (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:
1>      References=
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=Microsoft.CSharp
1>                  Redist=Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.4.5
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom=C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Configuration.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=System.Configuration
1>                  Redist=Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.4.5
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  Implicit=true
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=System.Core
1>                  Redist=Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.4.5
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=System.Data.DataSetExtensions
1>                  Redist=Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.4.5
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=System.Data
1>                  Redist=Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.4.5
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=System
1>                  Redist=Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.4.5
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=System.Xml
1>                  Redist=Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.4.5
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=System.Xml.Linq
1>                  Redist=Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.4.5
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0 (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:
1>      Sources=
1>          DataProvider.cs
1>          Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
1>          C:\Users\rutkor\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs
1>          obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs
1>          obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs
1>          obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:SubsystemVersion=6.00 (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:TargetType=Library (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:ToolPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:UseHostCompilerIfAvailable=True (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:Utf8Output=True (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:WarningLevel=4 (TaskId:25)
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Configuration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\CRDReportingClasses.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output DataProvider.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\rutkor\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs (TaskId:25)
1>Done executing task "Csc". (TaskId:25)
```

**Machine without issue**

```
1>Using "Csc" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "Csc" (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:DebugType=full (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:DefineConstants=DEBUG;TRACE (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:DisabledWarnings=;1701;1702;2008 (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:EmitDebugInformation=True (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:ErrorEndLocation=True (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:ErrorReport=prompt (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:FileAlignment=512 (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:HighEntropyVA=True (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:NoConfig=True (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:NoStandardLib=True (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:Optimize=False (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:OutputAssembly=obj\Debug\CRDReportingClasses.dll (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:Prefer32Bit=False (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:PreferredUILang=en-US (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:
1>      References=
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=Microsoft.CSharp
1>                  Redist=Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.4.5
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom=C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Configuration.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=System.Configuration
1>                  Redist=Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.4.5
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  Implicit=true
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=System.Core
1>                  Redist=Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.4.5
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=System.Data.DataSetExtensions
1>                  Redist=Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.4.5
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=System.Data
1>                  Redist=Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.4.5
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=System
1>                  Redist=Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.4.5
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=System.Xml
1>                  Redist=Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.4.5
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll
1>                  CopyLocal=false
1>                  FrameworkFile=true
1>                  FusionName=System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
1>                  ImageRuntime=v4.0.30319
1>                  OriginalItemSpec=System.Xml.Linq
1>                  Redist=Microsoft-Windows-CLRCoreComp.4.5
1>                  ReferenceSourceTarget=ResolveAssemblyReference
1>                  ResolvedFrom={TargetFrameworkDirectory}
1>                  Version=4.0.0.0 (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:
1>      Sources=
1>          DataProvider.cs
1>          Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
1>          C:\Users\deidad\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs
1>          obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs
1>          obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs
1>          obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:SubsystemVersion=6.00 (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:TargetType=Library (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:ToolPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:UseHostCompilerIfAvailable=True (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:Utf8Output=True (TaskId:25)
1>  Task Parameter:WarningLevel=4 (TaskId:25)
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Configuration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\CRDReportingClasses.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output DataProvider.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\deidad\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs (TaskId:25)
1>  Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 12.0.21005.1 (TaskId:25)
1>   (TaskId:25)
1>  for C# 5 (TaskId:25)
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. (TaskId:25)
1>   (TaskId:25)
1>Done executing task "Csc". (TaskId:25)
```

Comment: Hmm, that's novel.  You'll need to show us a detailed build trace.

Comment: I ran diagnostic logging builds on a machine with the issue and one  without the issue. As I suspected, the dll isn't getting built when the CSC task runs. Adding edits to main post...

Comment: Looks like csc.exe just terminated abruptly.  MSBuild doesn't know any better than it did its job so it keeps motoring.  This is going to require garlic and silver bullets.  Disable anti-malware, check if you can see anything with SysInternals' Process Monitor.